# How best to handle multiple .tfvars files that use common .tf files?

Tags: terraform, cdn

I am going to be managing the CDN configurations of dozens of applications through Terraform. I have a set of `.tf` files holding all the default constant settings that are common among all configurations and then each application has its own `.tfvars` file to hold its unique settings.

If I run something like `terraform apply --var-file=app1.tfvars --var-file=app2.tfvars --var-file=app3.tfvars` then only the last file passed in is used.

Even if this did work it will become unmanageable when I extend this to more sites.

What is the correct way to incorporate multiple `.tfvars` files that populate a common set of `.tf` files?

Edit: I should add that the `.tfvar` files define the same variables but with different values. I need to declare state of the resources defined in the `.tf` files once for each `.tfvar` file.

Comment: Have you come across the concept of [workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html) in Terraform yet?  Sounds like you need a workspace per `.tfvars` file.

Comment: I have not! I'll dig into workspaces, thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the best way to handle this case (without any 3rd party tools is to use) Terraform workspaces and create a separate workspace for each `.tfvars` file. This way I can use the same common `.tf` files and simply swap to a different workspace with `terraform workspace select <workspace name>` before running `terraform apply --var-file=<filename>` with each individual `.tfvars` file.

Comment: For using workspaces, do we need Terraform Enterprise? or can we use workspaces with Terraform open source version?

Comment: @Biju If you notice he's referring to the CLI "workspace" functionality (see https://www.terraform.io/language/state/workspaces), which is not tied to Terraform Cloud (ie. the Enterprise stuff). It's just coincidental that Terraform Cloud also uses the word "workspaces" to refer to a somehow similar feature. See https://www.terraform.io/cloud-docs/workspaces#terraform-cloud-vs-terraform-cli-workspaces

Answer (score 11):

This should work using [process substitution](https://superuser.com/questions/1059781/what-exactly-is-in-bash-and-in-zsh):

```
terraform apply -var-file=<(cat app1.tfvars app2.tfvars app3.tfvars)
```

Comment: What if `app1.tfvars` and `app3.tfvars` both happen to set a variable named `owner`? Wouldn't then the owner set in `app3.tfvars` override the owner that was set in `app1.tfvars`?

Comment: IIRC terraform aborts because a variable is being redefined

Answer (score 3):

Best Way may be the use of TerraGrunt https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/ from GruntWork, which is a thin wrapper around Terraform, you can use the HCL configuration file to define your requirements.

Sample terragrunt.hcl configuration:

```
terraform {
  extra_arguments "conditional_vars" {
    commands = [
      "apply",
      "plan",
      "import",
      "push",
      "refresh"
    ]

    required_var_files = [
      "${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/terraform.tfvars"
    ]

    optional_var_files = [
      "${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/${get_env("TF_VAR_env", "dev")}.tfvars",
      "${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/${get_env("TF_VAR_region", "us-east-1")}.tfvars",
      "${get_terragrunt_dir()}/${get_env("TF_VAR_env", "dev")}.tfvars",
      "${get_terragrunt_dir()}/${get_env("TF_VAR_region", "us-east-1")}.tfvars"
    ]
  }
```

You can pass down tfvars, also you can get more features from terragrunt by better organise your Terraform Layout, and use configuration file for passing tfvars from different locations.